# Getting TypeError after Async API Call with axios

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I'm trying to figure out some things that are occurring on my code.
I'm fetching some data from an Rest API I've made, and after an async call I'm getting:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined`

I can't figure out what is happening, because when I log the data on the console, I can see my Object populated with the correct info. Just to be sure that I've not made a type mistake, I've copied the data from the `console.log(response)` and created an Object and it worked.

Here's the call:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url_service_villain = "https://some_url/"

export const findRandomVillain = async () => {
    try {
        const {data} = await axios.get(url_service_villain + "find/random");
        return await data
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
};
```

And here is where I call the method:

```
import React from 'react';

import Character from './components/Character'

import {findRandomVillain} from './services/VillainService';

async function getRandomVillain(){
  const data = await findRandomVillain();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

function CharacterList(){ 
  const char = getRandomVillain();
  return (
    <section className="characterList">
      <Character key={char.id} images={char.images.md} name={char.name} powerstats={char.powerstats}/>
    </section>    
  )
};

export default CharacterList;
```

On the method `getRandomVillain()` the `console.log(data)` prints the object that I want,
but on the `CharacterList` I get the `TypeError` I listed above.

I also noticed on the top on the console window the following:

```
Promise {<pending>}  App.js:17
Promise {<pending>}  App.js:17
App.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'md' of undefined
    at CharacterList (App.js:20)
...{/*long list of errors here*/}
{id: "123", name: "Sinestro", powerstats: {…}, images: {…}} App.js:11
{id: "123", name: "Sinestro", powerstats: {…}, images: {…}} App.js:11
{id: "123", name: "Sinestro", powerstats: {…}, images: {…}} App.js:11
```

I think that is something related to the async call, and I don't know why the last line repeat 3 times, since I'm only logging it once.

Comment: Where do you try to access the `field` of something? The only place you've mentioned it is in the error message, not in the code

Comment: On the function `CharacterList()`, there's a `const char` that receives the data. I guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to handle the promise using `then(), catch()` to [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

the solution is to call `findRandomVillain()` when the component is ready by using `useEffect` and using `useState` to set the `char`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Character from "./components/Character";

import { findRandomVillain } from "./services/VillainService";

function CharacterList() {
  const [char, setChar] = useState();

  // using useEffect to make sure component is Ready
  useEffect(() => {
    findRandomVillain()
      .then((res) => setChar(res)) // handle promising
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  if (!char) return <div>loading</div>;
  
  return (
    <section className="characterList">
      <Character
        key={char.id}
        images={char.images.md}
        name={char.name}
        powerstats={char.powerstats}
      />
    </section>
  );
}

export default CharacterList;
```

Comment: Is it ok to put the useEffect on the first piece of code, where the api call is executed, I mean, is it a good practice?

Comment: yes it's good practise, `useEffect` in functional component is the same as `componentDidMount()` in class component,  you need to call your req when the component is ready

Answer (score 0):

When the react components is rendering. It will not wait the async call completed.  When the first time the react component mounted, the char is empty, but you are getting attributes values from char: "id"; "name". So you need add an exception to make sure when to render Component Character with char with successful API call.

> {char !== undefined (exceptions here) && }